# How do you determine if a pre-modifying past participle is a verb or an adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech, past-participles, premodifiers

How do you determine if a past participle--when used as a pre-modifier of a noun--is a verb or an adjective?

For example:

> a. *I saw a **broken** vase.*
>
> b. *I saw a **murdered** man.*

I think ***broken*** in a. is an adjective whereas ***murdered*** in b. is a verb. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Is there any clear way of determining the part of speech of a past participle pre-modifying a noun?

Comment: I agree with you. There are a few tests: “broken” can occur as complement to the complex-intransitive verb “seem” (“It seemed completely broken”). “Murdered” on the other hand fails all the tests: it can’t occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs (* ”He seemed/became quite murdered”), or to complex-transitive verbs (* ”I found him quite murdered”).

Comment: @BillJ Why do you think "It seemed/became broken" is possible while "He seemed/became murdered" is not? I mean, what kind of inherent difference between 'broken' and 'murdered' do you think makes the former construction possible and the latter construction impossible?

Comment: By looking at the syntactic evidence, such as I mentioned.

Comment: @BillJ I think your *quite* skews those tests.  **OK:** "Police found him murdered in his bed."  **??:** "'He looked murdered to me' said PC Blunt."

Comment: @StoneyB Are you saying that "found" in "Police found him murdered in his bed" or "He looked murdered to me" is an adjective?

Comment: (I assume you mean *murdered*, not *found*) I'm questioning the validity of BillJ's test. I have no problem with *murdered* being **both** an adjective and a verb at the same time--that's what a participle is, a form that "participates" in both categories.

Comment: @StoneyB (Yes I meant 'murdered'.) Then what's the reasoning behind thinking of 'murdered' in your sentences as an adjective? Just because 'murdered' describes a state of having been murdered?

Comment: Exactly. "... found him asleep", "... found him drunk", "... found him happy" -- they're all the same construction, with an object predicate.

Comment: @StoneyB If 'murdered' in your sentences is an adjective because it describes a state of having been murdered, 'murdered' in b. is also an adjective, right?

Comment: Does it matter whether you call it an adjective or a verb? In those sentences you list, both are participles being used as attributive modifiers.

Comment: @sky Do you think 'murdered' describes an attribute of 'man' in b.? If not, how can you call it an "attributive modifier"?

Comment: I can't see that there is any difference myself. If someone hits a vase with a hammer he has **broken** it, if he hits a man with a hammer he has **murdered** him. Either they are both adjectives (which is my preference as they describe the condtion of the subject) or they are both verbs.

Comment: I am with @sky on this. Is it not enough to say that both _broken_ and _murdered_ are past participle forms that can be used attributively, i.e. they  fulfil one of the tests that categorises words as adjectives? _Attributively_ in this context means premodifying the noun. For example, _afraid_ is an adjective that can __not__ be used attributively, and _mere_ is an adjective that can __only__ be used attributively.

Comment: @Shoe So are you saying that we can never know whether to classify a premodifying past participle as a verb or an adjective?

Comment: My point is that both _broken_ and _murdered_ pass one of the essential syntactic tests of adjectives, namely they can premodify nouns. _Broken_ also passes a morphological test of adjectives; it can take the prefix _-un_, which _murdered_ cannot. But neither pass the _can be made into an adverb test_: e.g. _happy > happily_, _broken > *brokenly_. As a teacher I am most interested in usage not classification. So the question _Is 'murdered' an adjective or a verb in the phrase 'a murdered man'?_ is not one that adds any value for me or my students. But I am willing to be persuaded otherwise!

Comment: @listeneva As Shoe suggests, the real question is Why do you want to classify it? What does the classification clarify?

Comment: @Shoe Non-adjectives can easily premodify nouns: In _a government policy_ and _all men_, _government_ and _all_ are not adjectives but a noun and a determiner, respectively. And would you teach your students that these are all adjectives? I hope not. So it's not that you're not interested in classification itself but it's just that some things are harder to classify than others. To face the hard questions or to avoid them and dismiss them as valueless  just because they're hard, that is the question.

Comment: @StoneyB It clarifies what an adjective is.

Comment: English learners need to know that you can premodify nouns with the present or past participle forms of many verbs, including _murder_: _the murdering man_, _the murdered man_. Whether you call such participles _verbs_ or _adjectives_  does not, in my opinion, advance their proficiency in the language.  Of course, for linguists it is a different story, and I would be interested if anyone can point to a definitive reference on the matter.

Comment: @Shoe So do you tell your students that _government_ and _all_ are adjectives? Or do you teach that not all pre-modifiers are adjectives?

Comment: No, I don't tell them that _government (committee), car (door), teacher (workroom)_, etc. are adjectives. I say that nouns can be used attributively (i.e. can premodify other nouns) - a very common feature of English. I've got 10 minutes to chat if you want.

Comment: I do think "murdered" is an attribute of "man" just as "broken" is an attribute of "vase". You could also consider longer attributive phrases like "the kettle *sitting on the stove* is about to boil", where "sitting on the stove" is an attribute of "kettle". I'm not sure if it's useful to ask whether they're verbs or adjectives in your example, since the usage is the same.

Comment: @sky When I say "adjectives describe attributes of nouns", I think the meaning of "attributes" is more narrowly interpreted than the meaning of "attributive" when _sitting on the stove_ is said to be an "attributive phrase". Otherwise, you'll end up saying that _sitting on the stove_ or _sitting_ is an adjective, which cannot be true. When you say "attributive", you actually mean that it modifies something, not that it is an adjective.

Comment: @Shoe How about _a voting committe_, _an opening door_, _a working room_? Do you tell your students that _voting_, _opening_ and _working_ here are adjectives or nouns? Or simply gerunds (or even participles)?

Comment: I never said they are adjectives, I said they are attributives. I think your question as you phrased it is meaningless. You are assuming that there there is a difference between "broken vase" and "murdered man". There is not. There may be a difference between "broken" and "murdered", as BillJ pointed out above, but that is in restrictions on their other uses. When used as pre-noun modifiers, they are grammatically identical. I would not use this example in teaching the difference between attributive verbs and adjectives, because in this example, there is no difference.

Comment: @sky I never said you said they are adjectives. If "broken" and "murdered" are the same, why is it that "broken" can be an adjective in "The vase was broken" while "murdered" cannot be an adjective in "The man was murdered"?

Comment: I just say that many words can be put in front of nouns to describe or identify those nouns, including adjectives, other nouns and verb forms. My students often make mistakes such as _She is a bored (i.e. boring) teacher_ or _I was disappointing (i.e. disappointed) with my grade_. Hence my comment above about being more concerning (i.e. _concerned_!) about usage than classification. Discussions about whether _bored_ in the sentence above is a verb or an adjective would not help students to express themselves correctly in such contexts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth F.E.'s answer there doesn't even discuss a single case of **a pre-modifying past participle**.

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish sometimes, but not always.

- *Very* can’t come directly before a verb.
- *Carefully* usually(?) won’t work before an adjective.

Neither of these tests seems to work very well for determining the part of speech of the words *broken* and *murdered* in your sentences. None of *I saw a very broken vase, I saw a carefully broken vase, I saw a very murdered man, I saw a carefully murdered man* sound natural to me.

Comment: If your test doesn't work for my question, how could this be an answer?

Comment: @listeneva: This post describes tests that can work for the general question ("How do you determine if a pre-modifying past participle is a verb or an adjective?" "Is there any clear way of determining the part of speech of a past participle pre-modifying a noun?"), even though they don't work for your specific example. If you don't find it helpful, that's fine. I just don't have anything better to offer at the moment.

Comment: I'd like your feedback on my own tentative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to edit the question, but I realized that the edit could amount to an answer on its own. So I'm going to post my own answer to my question so I can get some feedback.

While thinking about this question, I've come to realize that *broken* and *murdered* are inherently different in that they are allowed to be complements of different form of the verb 'be' when they are used as complements of the verb 'be':

The OP's examples can be rephrased as follows:

> a1. *I saw a vase that **was** broken.* (= a.)
>
> b1. *I saw a man that **had been** murdered.* (= b.)

In order for a1. and b1. to equate in meaning to a. and b., respectively, different forms of the verb 'be' should be used in a1. and b1.

In b2., for example, using the form ***was***, instead of the form ***had been***, renders the sentence even ungrammatical, much less having the same meaning as b.:

> b2. ??*I saw a man that **was** murdered.*

I don't know how to explain the ill-formedness of b2., compared with the well-formedness of a1., without the analysis that *murdered* in a. is not an adjective but a verb while *broken* in b. is not a verb but an adjective.

Comment: This post makes sense to me, but I'm not sure I agree about the dubiousness of "I saw a man that was murdered" with a stative sense. I mean, when I try to think about it, even "I saw a murdered man" seems kind of funny to me in terms of its meaning (like you're talking about seeing a ghost or something).

Comment: @sumelic Maybe I should be looking for a more natural sounding example.

Comment: Your interesting question has resurfaced, and you have added a further potential way of distinguishing _broken_ and _murdered_. Your question and answer seem to be based on the assumption that every given word in a given context can be definitively categorized. In this case, the claim is that _broken_ __is__ an adjective and _murdered_ __is__ a verb. If this is so, then presumably it should be possible, not just to list the various tests that the words do or do not pass, but also to state which of the tests are necessary or sufficient for placing the words into one or the other of the classes.

Comment: It is possible to conceive of a sentence _I saw a very murdered man_ (e.g. he had been shot, stabbed and bludgeoned). The ability to add _very_ is a characteristic of prototypical adjectives such as happy, so does this now make _murdered_ an adjective in this context?

Comment: @Shoe Well, I'm not as ambitious as you seem to think I am. I don't even know if what I've suggested can qualify as _a_ test, let alone _the_ test. I'm just trying to get some feedback about what I've been thinking. Regarding the _very murdered_ example of yours, I think it's one thing to think of a context in which the man had been murdered in a _very_ violent way, it's another to describe the man as _a very murdered_, which I find awkward at best, when you can describe him as _a brutally murdered man_.

Comment: Well, Google returns several results for "_very murdered_", many of which appear to be in humorous contexts.  But the question at the end of my last comment was a genuine one. It seems to me that certain words in certain contexts sit on a cline between, as in this case, a prototypical adjective and a prototypical verb. So making a binary choice is always going to be problematic unless the classification criteria are clear. Of course, it could be simply a matter of numbers: _broken_ passes more adjective tests than _murdered_ and _murdered_ more verb tests than _broken_.

Comment: Perhaps a linguist can help us out here.